# How to produce html text in UI popup using Google Apps Script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, popup

I have the following Google Apps Script:

```
function popUp() {
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var message = "<HTML><BODY>" 
  + "The meeting is at <b>10am</b>." 
  + "</BODY></HTML>";

var popUP = ui.alert(message, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

When I apply this function to a button in my Google Sheets, the popup pops up as expected.

However, the text in the popup carries all the "messy" HTML coding.

**How can I get the popup to show *actual* HTML formatted text?**

In other words, how can I make the UI popup use the HTML-laden text I added for var `message` but in a way that actually *formats* the text to use the HTML I added?

IS there some kind of HTML wrapper function?

---

**What I get vs what I want:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here's an [example dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45909430/7215091)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example closer to what you want. I don't think the alert takes html. It requires simple ascii text. Note: `google.script.host.close()` doesn't work when deployed as a web app.

```
function popUp() {
  var s='The meeting is at <strong>10:30AM</strong>.<br /><input type="button" value="OK" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s), 'PopUp');
}
```

See this in the 'Custom Dialog' documentation for Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs